# Any reason to use Date?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

There are at least three types which represent time: `Time`, `Date` and `DateTime`(from `ActiveSupport`).

My problem is, could `DateTime` totally replace `Date`? In other words, if I can use `DateTime`, is there any reason to use `Date` instead?

Comment: DateTime is in Ruby standard lib.

Comment: You do not appear to have really researched this question at all before asking. There are many discussions of DateTime vs Date vs Time on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
d = Date.today
dt = DateTime.now
p Date.public_methods - DateTime.public_methods
#=>[:today]
p DateTime.public_methods - Date.public_methods
#=>[:now]
p d.public_methods - dt.public_methods
#=>[]
p dt.public_methods - d.public_methods
#=>[:hour, :min, :minute, :sec, :second, :sec_fraction, :second_fraction, :offset, :zone, :new_offset]
```

DateTime is a subclass of Date. Using DateTime, you lose the `today` Class method and get `now` in return. You don't lose instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store only the date, for example a birthday, or a certain day where an event takes place, then it can be easier to use only date. Then you have no troubles which arise from different time zones and time zone calculations. If you use DateTime, then if you add an offset of -2 hours to 00:00 am, you get 10:00 pm of the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

Date does not store any information about the time, neither with the timezone. So you might get into trouble if at some point you'll need to use time data.

Cf [this link](http://elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails), which I found clear about what classes should be used, when, and how.